How to redirect in this specific pattern in .htaccess?
I need to use the .htaccess file to redirect, for example,  example.com/g/0/1/ to example.com/glink.html?LinkId=/0/1/ and example.com/g/a/4/ to example.com/glink.html?LinkId=/a/4/... etc. only when the path starts with /g/. How do I do this in the .htaccess file?

You simply implement a redirection rule that captures any requested path that starts with "g/" and proceeds with a sequence consisting of two numbers separated by a slash. You capture anything following the leading "g" and convert it into a get argument.
You will find many, many existing examples for such thing here on SO. Did you try any of those? Here is another one:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?g(/\d+/\d+/.*)$ to /glink.html?LinkId=$1 [QSA,L]

Best place to implement such a rule is in the central configuration of your http server's virtual host host section. If you do not have access to that you can use a distributed configuration file instead (typically called ".htaccess"), though that comes with a number of disadvantages. Keep in mind that you need to enable the interpretation of such files first (see the AllowOverride directive in the documentation) and take care to place the file in the folder configured as DocumentRoot of that virtual host and that it is readable by the http server process.
To learn how to implement such rewriting rules I again refer you to the documentation of the apache http server's  rewriting module.

I'm getting "500 Error, please check your php script / enable display_errors in your cpanel" when I visit my site

I use InfinityFree hosting, not my own apache server.

HTTP status 500 is just what the http server tells requesting clients. You as an administrator can obtain an precise error message by lloking into the http server's error log file. You will have to ask your hosting provider how you can access that information if you do not control that http server. If the information is not available to you then I suggest you switch your hosting provider. One simply cannot operate a web site without monitoring that file.

The rule itself looks OK to me. If your http server throws an http 500 it might simply be that the rewriting module is not loaded. Something that has to be done by the server operator.

Or, of course, it could be that it is not the http server that throws this error, but your own application logic. Again you will have to consult the http server's error log file, that is where you can simply read what the actual issue is. I clearly recommend against the suggestion to enable php's display_errors setting. That is not how one debugs a php scipt, that is amateurish fiddling, but not programming.

RewriteEngine works for everything hosted on my hosting provider

Except this.....

Interesting. So what did a look into the http server's error log file reveal? You have to do that yourself, we do not have access to that, obviously.

They said, "PHP errors are not logged on our hosting. If you want to see the error message your website generates, you can enable Display Errors on your website." I enable Display Errors and nothing happens.

As said before: that is not a professional way to handle the legitimate need for error logging. display_errors enabled in the php settings makes the engine just spill out one message per error somewhere in the created html structure which makes that structure invalid usually. Is is pure luck if you get a readable error message that way. You best bet is to open the source html code inside your browser and look if you can see some error message somewhere. I think that is a amateurish way to debug your code.

This still looks to me like the rewriting does work, but your php script is unable to process the rewritten request. Though that is just a guess on my side. Debugging one's application logic (your php script) is nothing that should be done on a live side, you certainly do that on your development environment. So on a local system where you have full control over the components and can look inside said error log file. Also enable rewrite logging, if required. You have much more options in your own environment. To me that sounds like the logical next step given your current situation.
